# Create paper wallet

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet, hardware-wallet

Which method do you suggest? I saw a video on youtube where somebody used bitaddress.org, but this video is quite old. 
Any ways you can suggest?

Frido

Answer (score -1):

Bitaddress.org works well. I still use it, meaning that it is not obsolete in any way. It's very easy to use to generate public/private key paper wallets.